# Problem compiling C/Fortran code together with pgi on windows: "main already defined"

Tags: c, windows, fortran, pgi

Below is a toy example of the C/Fortran files I want to compile together.

The C file

```
void testfunc();

int main(void)
{
    testfunc();
}
```

The Fortran file

```
subroutine testfunc() bind (C, name = "testfunc")
    write(*,*) "Hello World!"
end subroutine
```

Using gcc, I can generate a binary with the command

```
gfortran -o my_prog main.c testfunc.f90
```

However, when I try the same with pgf90

```
pgf90 -o my_prog main.c testfunc.f90
```

I get the following error message:

```
main.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in f90main.obj
f90main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MAIN_ referenced in function main
```

Is there a standard procedure for compiling C+Fortran with pgi on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the flag "-Mnomain" to the link to have the compiler not include the F90 main object to the link and instead use the user supplied C main.